# How to define non-required field in Mongoose schema with nested "type" property?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following Mongoose schema definition in my project:

```js
export const ProductSchema: SchemaDefinition = {
  type: { type: String, enum: constants.productTypes, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: false },

  espData: {
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    text: { type: String, required: true }
  },

  error: {
    type: {
      message: { type: String, required: true },
      statusCode: { type: Number, default: null }
    },
    required: false
  }
  // Some more definitions...
};
```

What's important from here is that I have collection of products where each product has its own `type` (which is a required string property that can have values defined in `constants.productTypes`), a non-required `name` field and so on. Also, there's `espData` field that has its own mandatory `type` property which is completely different from the top level `type`. And, there's `error` property that does not exist at all times, but when it does, it must have `message` property and optional `statusCode` property.

I now have to modify this schema so that `espData` becomes optional field since I may now have products that don't have this property. How do I do that? I tried couple of things, but none of them worked:

- First, I modified `espData` so that it looks the same as `error`:

```js
  espData: {
    type: {
      type: { type: String, required: true },
      text: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    required: false
  },
```

But, this is not working, most probably because there's so many nested `type` properties. Funny thing is that it perfectly works for the `error` property which has the same structure as `espData`, but without nested `type` property. The code I used is

```js
    const model = new this.factories.product.model();
    model.type = 'hi-iq';
    // model.espData purposely left undefined
    await model.save();
```

The error I'm getting is `Product validation failed: espData.type.text: Path 'espData.type.text' is required., espData.type.type: Path 'espData.type.type' is required.` This indicates that `model` created from schema is created as `espData.type.type` which is not what I wanted (I wanted `espData.type`).

- Second, I have tried the same from above, just instead of `required` field, I wrote: `default: null` which gave me an error `TypeError: Invalid value for schema path 'espData.default', got value "null"`.

So, how do I define `espData` as an optional field, which must have `type` and `text` properties when it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want. Create a new Document Schema with all the validations and nest it in another Schema with `required: false` (its default to false anyway)

```
const EspDataSchema = new Schema({
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  text: { type: String, required: true },
},
  {
    _id: false,
  }

);
```

example

```
export const ProductSchema = new Schema({

...
   espData: {
    type: EspDataSchema,
    required: false
   },

...

})
```

Comment: Yes, this is something I need. I also tried something like this, but I didn't use `new Schema()`. I just extracted `EspDataSchema` like this: `const EspDataSchema: SchemaDefinition = { type: { type: String, ...` which didn't really work. Thank you!